# Row grouping is not working in JQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I'm trying to add Row Grouping in JQuery Datatable as below. I want to group based on the first column.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover Devices" id="Devices">
    <thead style="color:white">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssetId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MobileDevice)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DeviceHolder.DeviceHolderName)
            </th>
       </tr>
    </thead>

<tbody style="color:black">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssetID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MobileDevice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeviceHolder.DeviceHolderName)
                </td>
           </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Devices').dataTable({ "bLengthChange": false, "bPaginate": false })
                .rowGrouping({
                    iGroupingColumnIndex: 0,
                    bExpandableGrouping: true


                });
    });
```

But it is not at all working. Please help me if there is anything wrong in this code.

Comment: Please define what is not working ... what errors are showing in console, if any.  What behavior are you seeing that you should not be.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. It only displaying simple datatable without any grouping.

Comment: I missed out mentioning that, the Accordion property is not working on Datatable Grouping. As a result, I need Asset ID is shown as heading with + symbol and when we click on that all the sub rows with same Asset ID should be displayed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/RgKPZ/ as an example

Answer (score -1):

Try to refresh your table using `<tablename>.fnDraw();`